# Emulating microcontroller peripherals

Tags: microcontroller, development, peripheral, emulator

When doing embedded MCU development, it's very helpful to emulate the MCU on a full PC, either via something like QEMU, or just directly targetting the PC in the compiler.

What about the peripherals, such as ADC, SPI, AES accelerator, and DMA? Is there any way to develop and test for those on a PC?

If not: How do I isolate those so that I can still run and test the higher layers on a PC?

For example: Could I use "Linux x86 PC" as an mbed target, and somehow simulate peripherals (or at least not refuse to compile due to their references in the code)?

Comment: I would be pretty amazed if this is possible, and even more amazed if it's advisable (since there are many fun quirks that may get overlooked by this, which you will have a fun time debugging when you switch to the mcu)

Comment: Sure there's technically a way. But without the design materials of the manufacturer's silicon I doubt it will be very reliable or time efficient. Certainly not more time or cost efficient than just running on the test hardware. "*How do I isolate those so that I can still run and test the higher layers on a PC?*" I imagine what you would do in practice is use an operating system on your target and write your code for that and emulate the operating system instead, or outright run the OS on your PC.

Comment: You're talking about the difference here between processor emulation and hardware simulation.  The latter is much more complex in modeling and demanding of resources.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the benefit of emulating the MCU on a full PC. Do you not have the target hardware available?

Comment: Of course it is possible. How exactly depends on at what level you want to emulate it and how accurate you want it to be. There is no single answer how to do it.

Comment: The thing is, it isn't just a matter of emulating the peripheral -- you also need to emulate at some level the behavior of the external device to which that peripheral is attached. For example, I once had to write an emulation for an external radio chip that was sufficiently detailed so that the MCU could execute its entire start-up sequence using the MCU's SPI controller.

Comment: Microchip's MPLABX, if I recall, does emulate the peripheral behavior for the devices it supports.

Comment: https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/introducing-mbed-simulator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preface

It makes a lot of sense to run the majority of the tests on a PC, compiled for the PC, at least to unit-test your application.

Yes, this way you don't run the target code, but that is not the test object. You test **your source** and so your algorithms. You trust your compilers, don't you? If not, you have a completely other problem.

And yes, this way you cannot test speed and performance requirements, because the target and the PC differ.

On the other hand, by simulating the peripherals or the HAL as described below you can execute *any* scenario, including "impossible<sup>TM</sup>" ones. You cannot do this with a real target.

The most valuable effect is for debugging, you can watch your code in ways that the real target simply cannot provide. You can bring the simulated target's world to a "full stop", enabling you to investigate any detail you wish. However, debugging is just a tool if tests fail.

#### How you could do it

The most common way is to design a software architecture that provides a HAL, a hardware abstraction layer. This layer should be as "thin" as possible. In many cases you don't need to test the HAL in depth with dynamic tests, serious code review is commonly sufficient. However, many manufacturers provide such a HAL, and you will not test that.

To run your unit and integration tests, compile for the PC and use a simulated HAL. The implementation of the simulated HAL can be of any degree, starting from a very simple behavior simulation, up to cycle-exact simulation. I never needed more than a simple behavior simulation, just enough to realize the test goals: check the arguments, and return needed results.

Depending on your target system, there are ready-made simulators available. Use them.

#### Final line

Running code only on the target is not "testing", as professional testers look at it. I would call it "trying", or "playing around", because of the limitations shown above.

However, as I said, speed and performance tests shall be run on a target. This *can* be a cycle-exact simulation of a target, but commonly is the real device.

Comment: If designed correctly, the PC will not simulate the HAL but rather the _drivers_ underneath the HAL. Correctly designed embedded systems have hardware <-> drivers <-> HAL <-> application. If it at all makes sense to test something in a PC, it is mainly the application layer that can be tested.

Comment: Many embedded system don't have drivers below the HAL. However, your remark is correct.

Comment: It's sensible to separate HAL and drivers since the main purpose of a properly written HAL is to allow portability between microcontrollers by just swapping out the drivers. Otherwise the HAL will quickly get cluttered down with compiler switches, strange references to some MCU-specific ISR or register map etc etc. There are problematic so-called "HAL" provided by ST, Microchip and others that don't have this functionality, because they do not want you to be able to port your code - they want you to be stuck on a specific MCU family.

Comment: Or you exchange the HAL, keeping the public API. :-D We might have different understanding of the term "HAL"...

Answer (score 1):

It mostly makes sense to test application-layer items on a PC, and only if you for some reason do not have the target hardware available, or in case you worry about special requirements such as portability. Various simulators of various quality exist - you need to decide if they are relevant or not on project basis. My general experience is that they create more problems than they solve, but that's subjective.

Most embedded systems use 8 to 32 bit microcontrollers and writing code which is portable to a 64 bit PC takes extra care and effort. If you have a *requirement* that the code must be wildly portable, then by all means implement that. If you have no such requirement, then compiling & running the code on a PC will mostly just be burdensome and irrelevant. There are lots of subtle difference between 64 bit PC compilers and <= 32 bit embedded system ones.

Furthermore, it will be extremely rare to encounter embedded systems projects written in 100% portable ISO C. There will be non-standard code handling interrupts, inline assembler, memory mapping, the CRT and so on. You cannot test that in a PC. Therefore it mostly makes sense to unit test individual modules of the application tier and not the project as whole.

However, simulating real-time critical hardware such as SPI or DMA on a PC is just nonsense - such tests  will prove absolutely nothing. Good practice involves always developing on the intended target hardware, even if that initially means using a generic evaluation board.

One of the main things of importance is memory use and memory mapping on the target. Experienced embedded developers keep track of this, check their map file on regular basis, make stack usage estimations and so on. And of course flash memory comes with a lot of special care in itself - perhaps it needs to be accessed in special ways due to Harvard architecture or because of extended memory addressing. Perhaps care must be taken about wait states. Perhaps you need CRC or ECC and similar. You cannot do any of this on a PC, only on the target.

Correct testing and/or benchmarking of embedded systems typically involves an oscilloscope or listener/logger tools, as well as a disassembler for the intended target. Testing should be considered early on when setting the project requirements, so that hardware adaptations and production tests are considered.

Comment: Inexperienced programmers also tend to wildly exaggerate not having the target hardware available as some major obstacle. Unless the PCB is very complex or your logistics channels are horrible, you should have the first prototype in your hand within a month or so from project start (though maybe with reservations for the on-going component shortage). This assuming that you specify key components early on and order samples, not doing the rookie mistake of ordering them at the point where the PCB is finished. Using an evaluation board in the meantime is usually not a big problem.